# avoid empty space in QTableView

Tags: qt, pyqt, qtableview, autoresize

In a QVBoxLayout added two QTableViews. The first one has constant number of rows (2), the second one has many. The goal is to make the second table begin just after last row in the first table.

I tried change QSizePolicy, setMinimumSize() - nothing helps. Here is sample of code:

```
layout = QVBoxLayout()
first_table = QTableView()
second_table = QTableVew()
first_table.setSizePolicy(QSizePolicy.Minimum, QSizePolicy.Minimum)
second_table.setSizePolicy(QSizePolicy.Expanding, QSizePolicy.Expanding)
layout.addWidget(first_table)
layout.addWidget(second_table)
```

It looks like it uses sizeHint() no matter of setMinimumSize(h, v) values. How to make the first table do not show space without rows?

Answer (score 1):

You might want to do the following:

```
layout = QVBoxLayout()
first_table = QTableView()
second_table = QTableVew()
layout.addWidget(first_table)
layout.addWidget(second_table)
layout.addStretch(1); // <--- to keep both tables together.
```

Comment: How to make the first table **do not show space without rows?**

Comment: @SergiiArtele, I don't understand what does it mean: `do not show space without rows`.

Comment: Thanks. If  your table view is larger than the area taken by rows, you cannot remove that extra space. The only way is to prevent the table view from resizing larger than its rows.

Comment: Probably I can use setFixedSize() but it is ugly way and the program crashes when I update model using table.model().clear() first